# to get link clicked in javascript/firefox-adon

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

Below is a code snippet for a Firefox add-on whose part of the job is to get the navigation details of the user (from which page to which page etc), but the code I used doesn't seem to work:

```
window.document.onunload = function()
    {   
        alert(document.location.href);
        alert(document.referrer);
    }
```

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** The onunload event for the window is called when the browser is closed. I want the function to be called when each page in the browser is unloaded.

Comment: Where exactly is this code placed? In a Firefox add-on, `window` normally refers to the top level Firefox browser window.

Answer (score 1):

The event handler should be binded to the `window` object, **not** to `window.document`. Any event listener which would be applied using `<body on{name of event} ...>` should dynamically be added to `window` instead of `document` / `document.body`.

Comment: Thanx for the help.so as you said i changed it to 
window.body.onunload = function()
but tha error sonsole says window.body is not defined

Comment: `window.onunload = function(){...}` should be used.

Comment: but the onunload event for the window is called wen the browser is closed.i want this to happen wen each page in the browser is unloaded

Comment: The `window.onunload` event listener is also called when the page is unloaded.

Answer (score 1):

`window.onunload = funcRef;`

For example: `<title>onunload test</title>`

```
<script type="text/javascript">

window.onunload = unloadPage;

function unloadPage()
{
 alert("unload event detected!");
}
</script>
```

Refer DOM section in Firefox/XUL: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onunload